# ms sql select/combine both tables and sort using inner join

Tags: sql-server

re: ms sql select inner join show records for both based on phone sort by date/time

I have two tables: `SMS_INBOX` and `SMS_OUTBOX`

They each have the same fields: `ID, DATE, MESSAGE, FROMPHONENUMBER`

The `DATE` format is like this: `10/25/2017 1:54:23 PM`

I would like to have it select the records based on the `FROMPHONENUMBER`
and the DATE/TIME.

I tried using inner join but I don't think I'm doing it right, no error, no records being returned.

```
SELECT * 
from SMS_OUTBOX 
  INNER JOIN SMS_INBOX 
    ON SMS_INBOX.FROMPHONENUMBER = SMS_OUTBOX.FROMPHONENUMBER 
where SMS_OUTBOX.FROMPHONENUMBER='1234567890' 
ORDER BY SMS_OUTBOX.ID DESC
```

Comment: The join syntax seems ok to me.  Are you sure the phone numbers are stored in the same format?  Have you checked the individual tables using your where condition?

Comment: Can you show data from both tables to validate your query?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the join.  I would first select from each table seperately where the phone number is 1234567890.  If they both return a result something seems strange.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Sorry the number was wrong. Thanks

Comment: Sorry the number was wrong. Thanks

Comment: @JonH Sorry the number was wrong. Thanks

Comment: YOU DONT HAVE TO YELL WE CAN SEE YOUR QUESTION

Comment: @Will copy that. Sorry & Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something to show a sms conversation? Then you might be looking for a `union`/`union all` type of query.

```
select id, date, convert(bit,1) as received_msg, message, fromphonenumber
from sms_inbox
where fromphonenumber = '1234567890'
union all
select id, date, convert(bit,0) as received_msg, message, fromphonenumber -- not tophonenumber?
from sms_outbox
where fromphonenumber = '1234567890'
order by date desc
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it!

Comment: What is the best way to to tell them apart when displaying ? should I add a prefix at the end when sending and then look for it ? before displaying and if it exists its a send message and if not then its a receive message

Comment: @compcobalt You can add a 'sent/received' direction column. Whatever makes the most sense to you.

Comment: So I added one more field called received_msg in sms_inbox and its a BIT True/False. but I cannot add it in the select/uniton all without adding it to both sms_inbox and sms_outbox.

Comment: @compcobalt You don't actually have to add the column to the table, you can just add the literals in the query. -- updated answer again to illustrate

Comment: Got it... THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH!!!! NOTHING BUT LOVE... THANKS AGAIN!!! AMAZING.